# MySQL not pulling correct results when comparing if float a <= float b, incorrect roundin may be the issue

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding, pervasive

I'm having issues with pulling data from some of my tables. The query that should be returning information is the following:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     tableone a,
         tabletwo b
WHERE    (a.RateCurrency = 'U')
AND      (a.EffectiveDate <= '2016-10-05')
AND      (a.ExpiryDate >= '2016-10-05')
AND      (a.TestOrProd = 'P')
AND      (a.TableKey = b.TableKey)
AND      (b.Min <= 2.39)
AND      (b.Max >= 2.39)
```

The problem is with b.Min. In the tabletwo the min value is 2.39, for some reason MySQL isnt picking up that 2.39 <= 2.39. If I change 2.39 to 2.4 in the query it pulls results, also if I go into tabletwo and change the Min value to 2.3899 it also pulls results.

Is there some sort of float rounding behaviour in MySql that I'm not aware of? (the datatype of Min is float)

Also I dont know if this makes a difference but we were using a Pervasive database previously and just moved to MySql...this issue occured in Pervasive as well so is there a common issue between the two?

Comment: Is it posible that `b.min` is actually something like 2.3899999... and is being displayed rounded to 2.39? You should be able to tell if you include an expression like `2.39 - b.min as diff` in your select clause (with the conditions amended to pick up the problematic record.)

Comment: I can't believe I didnt think of looking at it like that before, 2.39 - b.Min ends up being -0.000000104904174680343

Comment: Is the floating point arithmetic issue; binary floating can't represent decimal accurately. You may need to change the data type or as Mark Bannister mentioned you can work around by using difference in absolute value